# Highlight/Select Text using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to highlight/select the text from a huge text field. I was able to select the text using the below code, but it is selecting complete text. How do I select only the first few lines of the text.

```
cy.get('locator').first()
            .trigger('mousedown')
            .then(($el) => {
         const el = $el[0]
         const document = el.ownerDocument
         const range = document.createRange()
         range.selectNodeContents(el)
         document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(range)
         document.getSelection().addRange(range)
        
         })
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use native [setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) to select partial text.

```js
cy.get(selector).focus().then($el => {
  const el = $el[0]
  el.setSelectionRange(2, 5)
  const range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNodeContents(el)
  cy.document().then(document => {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(range)
    document.getSelection().addRange(range)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all of the text and then choose a [substring](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-using-slice-substring-and-substr-in-javascript.htm) of the selection.